# Constant RAM memory usage by windows service

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-leaks, windows-services, ram

I have a windows service developed in c# that runs daily at 10 am (set through a CRON expression).
It goes through a list of offices, for each office get a list of appointments, and for each appointment sends an email if certain conditions are met.

The execute method of the service is executed at 10, the services runs for 2-3 mins and then it is inactive in the next 24 hours (until it executes again for the next day).

Once the service is started and has finished running for the day, I can see that it is still present in task manager, with fairly high RAM usage (around 1.5GB). If I stop it and restart it from Services, then it is down to 0, but back again after the next day's run.

As far as I can tell there are not any memory leaks in it, and the tasks it does are fairly simple, so I'm not sure why the memory remains so high throughout the whole day (unless I stop it)

I'm adding the Execute method of the service bellow:

```
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            using var scope = _provider.CreateScope();
            InjectServices(scope);

            Log.Information("Service start");
            var allOfficesFirstShift = _officeInformation.ReadAllDueFirstShift();
            var allOfficesSecondShift = _officeInformation.ReadAllDueSecondShift();

            foreach (var office in allOfficesFirstShift)
            {
                var appointments = _appointmentInformation.ReadDueAppointments(office.id);
                foreach (var app in appointments)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var currentUser = _staffInformation.GetById(app.userId);
                        var body = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmailTemplates/reminderF.html"));

                        var recipientEmails = new List<string>();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.userEmail))
                            recipientEmails.Add(app.userEmail);
                        
                        var emailMessage = new EmailMessage
                        {
                            FromName = $"{currentUser.firstName} {currentUser.lastName}",
                            From = $"{office.OfficeName}",
                            ReplyTo = currentUser.userEmail,
                            Subject = "Reminder",
                            To = string.Join(",", recipientEmails),
                            IsHtml = true,
                            Body = body,
                        };

                       await _emailService.SendEmail(emailMessage);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.Information($"Reminder failure. Error: {e.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var office in allOfficesSecondShift)
            {
                var appointments = _appointmentInformation.ReadDueAppointments(office.id);
                foreach (var app in appointments)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var currentUser = _staffInformation.GetById(app.userId);
                        var body = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmailTemplates/reminderS.html"));

                        var recipientEmails = new List<string>();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(app.userEmail))
                            recipientEmails.Add(app.userEmail);

                        var emailMessage = new EmailMessage
                        {
                            FromName = $"{currentUser.firstName} {currentUser.lastName}",
                            From = $"{office.OfficeName}",
                            ReplyTo = currentUser.userEmail,
                            Subject = "Reminder",
                            To = string.Join(",", recipientEmails),
                            IsHtml = true,
                            Body = body,
                        };

                        await _emailService.SendEmail(emailMessage);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.Information($"Reminder failure. Error: {e.Message}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }

        Log.Information("Reminder job end");
    }
```

Comment: It's generally _not_ a good idea to tell the garbage collector when to run, but in this case, you have knowledge that the GC does not.... that the program won't do work for another 24 hours. Try manually collecting at the end of processing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=net-7.0

Comment: If you are using a .NET Core host, then [you have to shut the host down yourself](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/backgroundservice-gotcha-application-lifetime.html) (as explained on my blog).

Comment: @StephenCleary I'll try your suggestion with closing the app host and let you know of the results tomorrow morning :-) Thank you both for the suggestions!

Comment: @EricJ. I tried adding GC.Collect(); in a finally block at the end, but the memory usage did not change. I also tried emptying each list (and setting them to null, even though that doesn't make much sense) before calling the GC, but the memory usage is still high. Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong?